# How to detect list view scrolling direction in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have tried to detect the scrolling direction of the list view. My requirement is need to implement different functionality while list view scrolling up and scrolling down. Please suggest any idea for detecting list view scrolling direction. I have tried below syntax in my list view.

### Sample code:

```
 <StackLayout>
    <Label x:Name="Direction" />
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HasUnevenRows = "true" ItemAppearing="Handle_ItemAppearing" IsPullToRefreshEnabled = "true">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text = "{Binding}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can do it by default, you can only act on a item that is appearing or disappearing. So, you either need to work with that by creating some code which gets the index of (dis)appearing items and and see if the indexes are getting higher or lower to determine whether someone is scrolling up or down. Or you need to hook up a custom renderer, but I'm not sure the native controls have anything to detect this either.

I've whipped up a very basic example for you, you can find the [full code here](https://github.com/jfversluis/UpDownScrollSample).

Basically hook into the event available, keep track of the last index in a class variable and compare it to the current index of the item that is appearing.

```
private void Handle_ItemAppearing (object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
{
    var currentIdx = Items.IndexOf ((string)e.Item);

    if (currentIdx > _lastItemAppearedIdx)
        Direction.Text = "Up";
    else
        Direction.Text = "Down";

    _lastItemAppearedIdx = Items.IndexOf ((string)e.Item);
}
```

In this code I simply show it in a `Label`, but of course you can create some enum to return or fire an event or something to make the code some more reusable. Here is the code in action:

[image: Sample on iOS Simulator]

Comment: Hi Gerald Versluis, Thanks for reply. You have suggested ItemAppearing event but I have tried that one, It hit only at the time of data loading in a list then after when we try to scroll the content, it doesn't hit any more.

Comment: I'm sorry but then you did something wrong, this event hits every time an items is appearing, run the attached GitHub sample, it works.

Comment: My requirement is after loading data in list view, when user try to scroll the data need to detect he is scrolling up or down.

Comment: Sorry Gerald, I have run that sample code, it works great but I don't why list view doesn't fire itemappearing event.

Comment: But it works now? I don't quite understand your last comment.

Comment: Finally I find out why in my solution doesn't hit the itemappearing event. Cause of doesn't hit the event is In my list view I have set true for 'HasUnevenRows'. If we set false that it works great like you mentioned but I want to allow the uneven rows.

Comment: you can try with set HasUnevenRow is set to true in that example.

Comment: I have added the code what I have tried in that example in my question. Please try as like I have mentioned.

Comment: Please do not add code as an image. For searchability and copy/paste-ability add it as text.

Comment: After using your code the rows are very narrow, because of that there are not enough items in the list to scroll up or down. If I add more items, as much items so some items are out of the screen, then the code works fine again.

Comment: Without adding any extra item, I have set row height is 30 but not luck because I am not able to add any extra items. Is any alternative for getting same result.

Comment: Anyway thanks Gerald. Thank you very much for your patience. I have got the solutions finally with your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144431/discussion-between-deepak-and-gerald-versluis).

Comment: Surely scroll down means that you look at items further down the page?

Comment: I might have gotten the directions crossed, but the idea remains the same

Comment: @GeraldVersluis The ItemAppearing event might fire every time, but the ItemDisappearing does not when scrolling the listview at extremely high speeds. Tested on iPhone 11.

Answer (score 0):

Recently came through this problem and fixed it this way:

```
<StackLayout>
<Label x:Name="Direction" />
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HasUnevenRows = "true" ItemAppearing="Handle_ItemAppearing" ItemDisappearing="Handle_ItemDisappearing" IsPullToRefreshEnabled = "true">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                <Label Text = "{Binding}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

```
    string ScrollingDirection;
    int visibleTabIndex;
    int disappearingTabIndex;

    public async void Handle_ItemAppearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
    {
        var visibleTab = e.Item;
        visibleTabIndex = MyItemsList.IndexOf(visibleTab);
        if (disappearingTabIndex > visibleTabIndex) ScrollingDirection = "DOWN";
        else ScrollingDirection = "UP";

    }

    public async void Handle_ItemDisappearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
    {
        var invisibleTab = e.Item as TicketsList;
        disappearingTabIndex = tvm.Tickets.IndexOf(invisibleTab);


    }
```